# Как добавить элементы в массив и удалить из него?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Как правильно добавить в текущий массив `pays` элемент и удалить из него?

```
dataUser: [{
    name: 'Alex',
    time: '8.09.2020',
    products:[
      pays:[]
    ],
  },
  {
    name: 'Ivan',
    time: '8.01.2020'
  },
  {
    name: 'Olga',
    time: '8.02.2020',
    products:[
      pays:[]
    ],
  }],
```

```
<p v-for="product in products">
  <p v-for="(pay, index) in product.pays">
    <button class="btn" @click="addRowPay"></button>
    <span v-on:click="removePay(index)" class="fe fe-trash-2"></span>
  </p>
</p>
```

```
addRowPay(){
  this.product.pays.push({price: 0, days: 0});
},

removePay(index){
  this.product.pays.splice(index,1);
};
```

Comment: this.product - не существует, судя по коду, такого свойства

Answer (score 1):

Нашел решение:

```
<p v-for="(product, int) in products">
  <p v-for="(pay, index) in product.pays">
    <button class="btn" @click="addRowPay(int)"></button>
    <span v-on:click="removePay(int, index)" class="fe fe-trash-2"></span>
  </p>
</p>
```

```
addRowPay(int){
  this.products[int].pays.push({price: 0, days: 0});
},

removePay(int, index){
  this.products[int].pays.splice(index,1);
};
```